# Um sistema Web poderia ser considerado como um software?

Tags: aplicação-web, software

A dúvida é se um sistema web poderia ser considerado um software. Quais as definições de sistema web? Quais as definições de software? E qual o limiar entre eles?

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma explicação legal no site https://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2015/04/voce-conhece-a-diferenca-entre-software-e-sistema/ sobre isso.

Resumindo, o software é aquilo que você vai instalar no computador ou outro dispositivo, possui executavel, bibliotecas,etc..
Sistema é um conjuto de softwares que se interagem em vista de um objetivo comum.

Então um sistema web é sim um software, mesmo não possuindo executável, ele possui bibliotecas, banco de dados, ferramentas ,etc...

> Escrevemos linhas de código na nossa ferramenta de desenvolvimento e
>   compilamos os arquivos para gerar um executável, certo? Esse
>   executável (também conhecido como artefato) é o que chamamos de
>   software. Em outras palavras, é o programa que será instalado no
>   computador do usuário e disponibilizado para uso. Mas não é só isso! O
>   termo “software” ainda engloba os arquivos que serão distribuídos com
>   o executável, como bibliotecas, banco de dados, demais arquivos de
>   configuração e, claro, a documentação do programa.
>
> Um sistema, por sua vez, é um conjunto de softwares que se interagem
>   para atingir um objetivo em comum. Portanto, quando mencionamos
>   “sistema”, estamos nos referindo a uma solução abrangente que envolve
>   várias partes interligadas, oferecendo um composto de funcionalidades
>   para atender as necessidades do usuário.